# Format custom numeric string with fixed character count

Tags: c#, formatting, string-formatting

I need to convert any number in a fixed format with a fixed amount of characters. Means 1500 and -1.5 or 0.025 need to have the same length. I also have to give the format in this form: `Format = "{???}";`

When i type `Format = "{0000}";` i can limit 1500 to "1500", but -1.5 -> "-0001.5" means i have too much numbers after the point.

Negative sign place can be done with `Format = "{ 0.0;-0.0; 0.0}"`.

How can i fix the count of the numbers for different numbers?

The length of the string doesn't matter, the most important is the equal length.

Examples:

```
1500 ->    " 1500.000" or "     1500"
-1500 ->   "-1500.000" or "-    1500" or "    -1500"
1.5  ->    "    1.500" or "      1.5"
-0.25->    "   -0.250" or "-    0.25"
0.00005 -> "    0.000" or "        0"
150000->   " 150000.0" or "   150000"
15000000   " 15000000"
```

Edit:

I want to Format an y-Axis of a Chart. I **can't use** something like `value.ToString("???")` i need to use `chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{???}";`

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with format strings alone. You might need to play around with [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Math.Round.aspx) and [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use formatting?  "F3" forces 3 digits after decimal point and PadLeft ensures the overall length

```
  Double value = 1500.0;
  // 3 digits after decimal point, 9 characters length
  String result = value.ToString("F3").PadLeft(9, ' ');

         0 ->     0.000
    1500.0 ->  1500.000
   -1500.0 -> -1500.000
     -0.25 ->    -0.250
```

Another (similar) possibility is String.Format:

```
  Double value = 1500.0;
  // Put value at place {0} with format "F4" aligned to right up to 9 symbols
  String result = String.Format("{0:9,F4}", value);
```

Comment: The `' '` is the default, so it is not absolutely necessary. `0.00005.ToString("F3")` will produce `"0.000"`, but be aware, that `0.0005.ToString("F3")` will produce `"0.001"`.

Comment: I need this form: `chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{???}";`. I can't use ToString() and PadLeft()

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This don't work for me. When i use `{0:9,F4}` i get as result 0F4, up to 2F4 (my values go up to 1500). I tried this ":" and `{0:000000}` would result like "000013".

Answer (score 0):

Try it > `result = Math.Round(yourValue, 3);`
Check full reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) !

Answer (score 0):

you  cannot achieve this by  a simple format function

```
   string result = string.Empty;

        var array = dec.ToString().Split('.');
        if (dec > 0)
        {

            result = array[0].PadLeft(9).Remove(0, 9);


            if (array.Count() > 1)
            {
                result += '.' + array[1].PadRight(3).Remove(3);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            result = "-"+array[0].PadLeft(9).Remove(0, 9);
            if (array.Count() > 1)
            {
                result += '.' + array[1].PadRight(3).Remove(3);
            }

        }
```